# ASP.NET Head sections is not getting modified?

Tags: asp.net, css

I have following code structure, where i am trying to change the css file href during runtime. I also have the Update Panel, Script Manager in the page.

It looks like that CSS file is not getting changed/loaded by the browser. I am not able to understand why?

```
<head>
<link runat="server" id="link1" type="text/css" href="TOBE SET ON RUNTIME.CSS"/>
</head>

//Code to change the stylesheet on page load
    link1.Attributes["href"] = GetCSSFileName(this.UserId);
```

Thanks

Comment: can you show the code as to how you are trying to set the href attribute of the link?? - where is this code being called - ~Page_Load, Load_Complete???

Comment: I suspect that probably Script Manager is not allowing to load the files into the browser. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your head section to have ID and RUNAT="server" attribues

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
   <link runat="server" id="link1" type="text/css" href="TOBE SET ON RUNTIME.CSS"/>
</head>
```

You can set CSS stylesheet from codebehind like this

```
link1.Attributes.Add("href", "mycustomstyle.css");
```

Comment: Yes i did that... it shows the file in head if i see the view source code. However the browser is not interpreting/loading it ...

Comment: @Anil.Are you sure that your path to the CSS is correct ? User firebug to make sure that you loaded the correct css file (i mean the proper path). The above code worked for me.Did you try it without the script manager in your part ? I did'nt have script manager in my page

Comment: @Anil Namde: It doesn't matter how it is generated (programatically, etc.) the source HTML that the browser has is all that matters.If it is showing what you think is the right CSS link and it is not loading then there is something wrong with that link. Can you load it directly (using the url in the page rather than typign it in yourself in case there is a minor typo causing problems).

Comment: I found that the page has script manager. I tried without script manager and it worked. Is there any work around / way to make it work with the script manager ? I tried the firebug and its not downloading the CSS as shown by the CSS requests.